Lacunary function - $\sum_{n \geq 0} z^{2^n}$; $w \in \mathbb{C}$ such that $w^{2^n}=1; n \in \mathbb{C}$

Consider $f(z)=\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} z^{2^n} $ defined on $D(0,1)$

For every $n \in \mathbb{N}$; given a $2^n$-th root $w$ of unity ;$\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} w^{2^n} $ diverges, with this in mind, I'm trying to show that there is no analytic continuation over a open connected set that contains strictly $D(0,1)$; I thought about the continuous map $x \rightarrow e^{2\pi i  x}\;; x \in [0,1) $ then for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$, any element of $\{\frac{m}{2^n} \mid m=0,1, \dots 2^n-1 \}$  would be mapped to a $2^n$-th unity of root and as $\{\frac{m}{2^n} \mid n \in \mathbb{N};m=0,1,2,\dots, n-1 \}$ is dense over $[0,1]$, then I'd have that the mapped set would be dense over $S^{1}$ and I couldn't arrange an analytic continuation of $f$ because for every $z \in S^1$ there'd be an arbitrarily close singularity to $z$. Is this correct? Any kind of suggestion?
EDIT:
I also have that:
$$(\forall n \in \mathbb{N});f(z^{2^n})=f(z)-\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}z^{2^k}$$

This function has been mentionned in a question asked 3 hours ago... See the references I have given.
